# Handling JSON response React Native

Tags: json, react-native

I'm following the React Native documentation for fetching JSON from an API (https://reactnative.dev/docs/network). I'm new to react and wanting to fetch a wordpress list of posts through its API, but the example they use is very simple and structured differently to how the object is returned from WP.

The problem I'm having is that it is returning the JSON, but I'm unsure how to reference each item I want to display in my flatlist. The line of problem is;

```
.then((json) => setData(json.movies))
```

For this WP returned JSON, there is no movies (obviously), in the absence of a referable point what would I specify instead?

My code;

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/derbyfutsal.com/posts')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.movies))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item.title}, {item.excerpt}</Text>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to specify anything, you can directly set the response to the state value and use it in the flatlist.
I've updated the code to display the id instead of title as its an object. You can change it anyway you want and use it.

```
const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/derbyfutsal.com/posts')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setData(json)
        })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>{item.id}</Text>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Gureparan, it didn't like const App = () => {, but worked on export default App = () => {, but it works , I'm just going to work out now how to work with the objects elements of the JSON :). Thanks again